# Как передать вещественные данные из одной Activity в другую?

Tags: java, android, activity, float, android-intent

В первом `Activity` создаём два `EditText` и один обработчик. Введённые данные `float` обрабатываем нужными формулами, и результат передаём в два `TextView` другого `Activity`.

Я начинающий Android-разработчик и у меня никак не получается это реализовать.

Кто-нибудь может привести мне пример? Вот мой неудачный код:

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText login;
    private EditText password;
    float result;
    float result1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    }

    public void sendata (View view){
        float num1 = 0;
        float num2 = 0;
        float result = 0;
        float result1 = 0;
        // Проверяем поля на пустоту
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(login.getText().toString())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString())) {
            return;
        }
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(login.getText().toString());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(password.getText().toString());
        result = (float) ((Math.log(1 / num1)));
        result1 = (float) (1 - num1);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("login", result);
        intent.putExtra("pass", result1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity**:

```
public class secondactivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtlogin;
    private  TextView txtpassword;
    String str1;
    String str2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
        txtlogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtlogin);
        txtpassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        String str1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("login");
        String str2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("pass");
        txtlogin.setText(str1);
        txtpassword.setText(str2);
        //txtlogin.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("login"));
        //txtpassword.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("pass"));
    }

    public void onback (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Под "интэнт" вы, видимо, имеете в виду "активити"? Если да, то покажите ваш код (не весь а часть коя не получается).

Comment: Путаете концепцию intent и activity. На свой вопрос ответ найдете в первых 80 страницах любого(наверное) учебника по Android. А-то из-за такой глупости(из-за вас) представление о разработчике катится.

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent

Comment: @0xFFh, представление о разработчике меняется потому что меняется суть программирования. [Joke] Computer Programming To Be Officially Renamed “Googling Stackoverflow” http://www.theallium.com/engineering/computer-programming-to-be-officially-renamed-googling-stackoverflow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первой Activity, где находится 2 EditText'a, после обработки вызываем Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("etFirst", mEditText1.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("etSecond", mEditText2.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Во второй Activity создаете переменные, String например и присваиваете им переданные значения следующим образом

```
String str1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("etFirst");
String str2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("etSecond");
```

Comment: Это код я давно нашел но мне нужно введенные данные обработать и передать во 2 активити. А этот код просто передает данные  из EditText 1-ое активити в TextView 2-го активити

Comment: Я не крутой чувак тока учусь . starandroid уроки смотрел .побовал совместить 19 урок с 28. Для того чтобы передать обработанные данные во 2-ой интент.

Comment: Вместо `mEditText1.getText().toString()` можно подставить обработанные данные. Например создать глобальную переменную в первой Activity, после обработки присвоить ей полученное значение и передать через Intent выше описанным методом.

Comment: Я верху код написал но передать данные не получилось((

Comment: Какой тип данных Вы передаете? Если String, то при получении необходимо указывать getIntent().getStringExtra("имя"). Если int, getIntent().getIntExtra("имя", "значение по умолчанию").

Comment: я передаю данные float

Comment: тогда во второй Activity просто необходимо вызвать метод getFloatExtra("имя", "значение по умолчанию"). Полностью это выглядит так float value = getIntent().getFloatExtra("имя", "значение по умолчанию")